# Doubt about $H_{\infty } $ norm of a transfer function

Tags: normed-spaces, control-theory

I have a doubt about the $H_{\infty } $ norm of a transfer function. Suppose I have  a transfer function:

$T(s)=C(sI-A)^{-1}B+D$

I have seen that

$\lim_{t->\infty } T(j\omega ) = D$

so, it means that the $||T||_{\infty } = D$. But I don't understand how this result comes out.

Infact, if I do the limit of the transfer function $T(s)=C(sI-A)^{-1}B+D$ I have :

$\frac{CB}{A}+D$

can somebody please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you meant to define the infinity norm as follows

$$
\|T\|_\infty = \lim_{\omega\to\infty} T(j\,\omega),
$$

so taking the limit in $\omega$ instead of $t$. In this case it can be noted that when the absolute value of $s$ is really large it holds that that $s\,I - A \approx s\,I$, so

\begin{align}
\|T\|_\infty &= \lim_{\omega\to\infty} C\,(j\,\omega\,I - A)^{-1} B + D, \\
&= \lim_{\omega\to\infty} C\,(j\,\omega\,I)^{-1} B + D, \\
&= \lim_{\omega\to\infty} \frac{C\,B}{j\,\omega} + D, \\
&= D.
\end{align}

However, it can be noted that the [infinity norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-infinity_methods_in_control_theory#Problem_formulation) can also refer to

$$
\|T\|_\infty = \sup_\omega \bar{\sigma}(T(j\,\omega)),
$$

with $\bar{\sigma}(X)$ the largest singular value of $X$. This definition in general does not give the same value as the one defined in my first equation.

The equation that you obtained is the limit of $s$/$\omega$ to zero

$$
\lim_{\omega\to0} T(j\,\omega) = C\,A^{-1} B + D.
$$

Comment: Thanks for answering. So, just to be sure I have undrestood, if I have a linear system x_dot = Ax+Bu   y=Cx+Du, then the H infinity norn of the transfer function of it is always D? And so what I have written, so CB/A is complitely wrong right? Thanks again.

Comment: The H-infinity norm is normally defined as the second norm in my answer (so with the largest singular value). I believe that in general that a norm should return a scalar and the first norm in my answer (with the limit of $\omega$ to infinity) doesn't in general for MIMO systems. What you wrote, $C\,A^{-1} B+D$, would be solution to $$\lim_{s\to0} T(s).$$

Comment: Thanks again for answering. While studying this argument,I have found a transfer function which is $\frac{b}{s+a}$ and that its H-infinity norm is  $\frac{b}{a}$. But why in this case was ok to do the limit for $s->0$? Thanks again.

Comment: sorry, I cannot edit anymore my comment, but in the fraction please consider capital letters.

Comment: @J.D. the H-infinity norm is equal to the second definition for $\|T\|_\infty$ I gave in my answer, which requires finding the value for $\omega$ which maximizes $\bar{\sigma}(T(j\,\omega))$. It can be noted that for scalar/SISO transfer functions the largest singular value is just the absolute value. It is just that for your example transfer function this solution turns out to be at $\omega\to0$. However, in general it is not always the case that the H-infinity norm means you have to evaluate the transfer function at $\omega\to0$ or $\omega\to\infty$.